# how to use mnesia:select/4 and mnesia:select/1 for paging query

Tags: mnesia

a table named "md" with structure {id,name},I want read records from md use paging query,I tried mnesia:select/4 and mnesia:select/1 as below:

```
%% first use select/2: "ID < 10",returned [1,2,4,3,8,5,9,7,6]
(ejabberd@localhost)5> mnesia:activity(transaction,fun mnesia:select/2,md,                 [{{md,'$1','_'},[{'<','$1',10}],['$1']}]).
{atomic,[1,2,4,3,8,5,9,7,6]}

%%but when query with select/4,returned [6], why?
(ejabberd@localhost)7> {atomic,{R1,C1}}=mnesia:activity(transaction,fun mnesia:select/4,md,[{{md,'$1','_'},[{'<','$1',10}],['$1']}],5,read).
{atomic,{[6],
     {mnesia_select,md,
                    {tid,10535470,<0.460.0>},
                    ejabberd@localhost,disc_only_copies,
                    {dets_cont,select,5,
                               <<0,0,0,29,18,52,86,120,0,0,0,21,131,104,3,...>>,
                               {141720,148792,<<>>},
                               md,<0.130.0>,<<>>},
                    [],undefined,undefined,
                    [{{md,'$1','_'},[{'<','$1',10}],['$1']}]}}}
%% and then use mnesia:select/1 with continuation "C1",got wrong_transaction
(ejabberd@localhost)8> mnesia:activity(transaction,fun mnesia:select/1,C1).
{aborted,wrong_transaction}
```

how to use mnesia:select/4 and mnesia:select/1 for paging query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution:
use **async_dirty** instead of **transaction**

```
{Record,Cont}=mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/4,[md,[{Match_head,[Guard],[Result]}],Limit,read])
```

then read next **Limit** number of records:

```
mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/1,[Cont])
```

full code:

```
-record(md,{id,name}).
batch_delete(Id,Limit) ->
    Match_head = #md{id='$1',name='$2'},
    Guard = {'<','$1',Id},
    Result = '$_',
    {Record,Cont} = mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/4,[md,[{Match_head,[Guard],[Result]}],Limit,read]),
    delete_next({Record,Cont}).

delete_next('$end_of_table') ->
    over;
delete_next({Record,Cont}) ->
    delete(Record),
    delete_next(mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/1,[Cont])).

delete(Records) ->
    io:format("delete(~p)~n",[Records]),
    F = fun() ->
        [ mnesia:delete_object(O) || O <- Records]
    end,
    mnesia:transaction(F).
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call select/1 inside the same transaction.

Otherwise the table can change between invocations to select/4 and select/1.

You must use a dirty context if you want to use is as written above.

Comment: yeah,I think you are right.now I use a dirty context:
{Record,Cont}=mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/4,[md,[{Match_head,[Guard],[Result]}],Limit,read]),but what make me confused is it return inequality numbers of record when i use mnesia:activity(async_dirty, fun mnesia:select/1,[Cont]) recursively.

Comment: misleading answer as `Notice that any modifying operations, that is, mnesia:write or mnesia:delete, that are done between the mnesia:select/4 and mnesia:select/1 calls are not visible in the result.`